# Source code using a structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()    
{    
struct stock     {     
    char symbol[5];     
    int quantity;    
    float price;    
};    
struct stock *invest;

/*Create structure in memory */
invest=(struct stock *)malloc(sizeof(struct stock));
if(invest==NULL)
{
    puts("Some kind of malloc() error");
    exit(1);
}
/*Assign structure data */
strcpy(invest->symbol,"GOOG");
invest->quantity=100;
invest->price=801.19;

/*Display database */
puts("Investment portfolio");
printf("Symbol\tShares\tPrice\tValue\n");
printf("%-6s\t%5d\t%.2f\t%%.2f\n",\
       invest->symbol,
       invest->quantity,
       invest->price,
       invest->quantity*invest->price);         /*  I dont understand this line */

       return(0);

}
```

- In the final output

Symbol - GOOG
Shares -100
Price - 801.19
Value - %.2f

- How is the final pointer reference at `line33` leading to the output %.2f ?
  (i do understand that the %% is used to display a %]
- Why exactly is memory reallocated in a program?

Suppose, If i were to add a `realloc()` function in the code for the *invest* pointer, how is it going to affect the program or make it better in terms of performance?
How does `realloc()` helps in 'freeing' the memory?

(Iam not able to quite understand the relation of `realloc()` with `malloc()`)

Comment: *i do understand that the %% is used to display a %*. That is why `%%.2f` outputs `%.2f`.

Comment: Also note: You seem to be compiling without warnings. `invest->price=801.19` should raise a narrowing warning. `801.19` is a `double` literal that gets stuffed into a `float` value (try `801.19f`).

Comment: I use `code::blocks`, in which i might need to change the settings for compiler.It sometimes does not shows warning for codes that are intended to show warnings for beginners.Little help?

Comment: Mandatory link about [casting the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Now what I really would like to know is, who are all the imbeciles who keeps teaching beginners to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%%.2f needs an extra % symbol to make the final .2f into a format rather than the string literal that's being displayed.

Secondly realloc is intended to resize a previously calloc-ed array in memory.

Answer (score 0):

> How is the final pointer reference at line33 leading to the output %.2f ?

Because `%%` causes printf to display a `%` sign and not treat the second `%` as the start of a format specifier.  That leaves `.2f` which is just literal characters in printf terms to be printed verbatim.

> Why exactly is memory reallocated in a program?

`realloc` is used to change the size of a previously malloc'd memory region whilst preserving as much of the data in it as possible.  In your case you allocated enough memory to store one instance of `struct stock`.  If you decided you wanted two instances, you could do this:

```
invest = realloc(sizeof(struct stock) * 2);
```

That is almost equivalent to

```
struct stock* newInvest = malloc(sizeof(struct stock) * 2);
memcpy(newInvest, invest, sizeof(struct stock));
free(invest);
invest = newInvest;
```

The difference is that `realloc` can check the original block of memory to see if it can just be extended which is considerably faster than allocating a new block, copying the data and freeing the old block.

> I dont understand this line

```
invest->quantity*invest->price);
```

It's simply an expression that multiplies the quantity and the price.